# Deleting from the database table

Tags: php, pdo

I want to give user possibility to delete other users. I made a script where user get list over all users with delete button. Button start the script but doesn't delete user from the list. Here is my code:

```
                                    function get_userlist(){
            $select_users = $this->db->prepare("SELECT user_id, fname, lname, email
                                            FROM user");
            $select_users->execute();

            echo "<tbody>";

            while($row = $select_users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo "<form action='' method=''><tr><td>".$row["user_id"]."</td><td>".$row["fname"]."</td><td>
                ".$row["lname"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."</td><td>
                <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value=".$row["user_id"] . " >
                <input type='submit' name='submit_delete' value='Delete'></td>
                </tr></form>";

            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";
        }

        function delete_user($user_id)
        {
            $delete_user = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = :user_id");
            $delete_user->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $delete_user->execute();
        }
```

And file where I use those functions:

```
$user = new USER($con);
$user->get_userlist();

if(isset($_POST['submit_delete'])){
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $user->delete_user($user_id);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `function delete_user()` should be `function delete_user($user_id)` also `':user_id, $user_id'` should be `':user_id', $user_id`

Comment: Updated function with ($user_id) but what do u mean 'by `:user_id, $user_id' should be ':user_id', $user_id`

Comment: Your html has an extra </td> after the two input tags. Either that or I can't find the opening tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing $user_id variable to your delete_user function. Edit your code like this:

```
function delete_user($user_id)
{
        $delete_user = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = :user_id");
        $delete_user->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $delete_user->execute();
}
```

Comment: @ShabbyAbby Did you edited this line too  ? `$delete_user->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);`

Comment: Yes looks like that:
            `function delete_user($user_id)
            {
                    $delete_user = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = :user_id");
                    $delete_user->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
                    $delete_user->execute();
            }`

Comment: @ShabbyAbby I edited my answer, can you try again with new one.

Comment: @ShabbyAbby Also I saw that in get_userlist() function, your  `</form>` tag inside the while loop. Can you move it to this line:  `echo "</tbody></table>";`  it should be:  `echo "</form></tbody></table>";`

Comment: Updated code in orginal post with your tips, still not working :(

Comment: @ShabbyAbby Whats the data type of user_id column in your Database ? If it is not integer change PDO::PARAM_INT to PDO::PARAM_STR

Comment: @ShabbyAbby Can you add inside end of the delete_user function these lines, lets see whats returning `print_r( $this->db->errorInfo()); echo $user_id;`

Comment: Strange, dont get any result of this line

Comment: @ShabbyAbby edit this and look are you entering inside the post ? It should echo user ıd. Also in this code, first you should delete the user then get the user list. `$user = new USER($con);if(isset($_POST['submit_delete'])){     $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];   echo  $user_id; $user->delete_user($user_id); } $user->get_userlist();`

Comment: @ShabbyAbby ok i saw the problem. I dont know where it is but Move your <form opening  tag inside the while loop right before <tr><td> tag. Also move form closing tag </form> to inside the while after </tr> tag. Also move <tbody> opening tag to outside the while loop.

Comment: @mertizci I noticed the html is formatted improperly as well. I think there is an extra </td> closing tag as well.

Comment: @mertizci Tried to clean up HTML as you said, but no better result. I tried to call get_userlist() after delete_user() but it doesn't work. Updated script in orginal post.

Comment: @ShabbyAbby begining of form tag method should be post. `method='post'`

Comment: Omg, so embarrassed. `method='post'` was the solution! Thank you very much!